# How to Update Progressbar in GridView Adapter using BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to perform have scenario,

I am using Custom `TouchyGridView`
Everything was working fine.

But now I want to add new functionality.

I want to download APK file in the background. So When downloading start, I want to show new icon in grid view and progress bar upon new grade item.

*I know How to download from the server.

And `ProgressBar` should be updating using `progressbar.setProgress(progress);`

[image]

How can I do this?

I tried `BroadCastReceiver`, but didn't get success, because my broadcast is in MainActivity and View is in the adapter, So How can I update view of Adapter class using `BroadCastReceiver`?

**grid_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid_app_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_app_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="app"
        android:textColor="@color/content"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**HomeScreenAppGridAdapter.java**

```
public class HomeScreenAppGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<KioskAppDetail> mAppList;

    private PackageManager mPackageManager;
    private String tag = "GridAdapter";

    // Constructor to initialize values
    public HomeScreenAppGridAdapter(Context context,
                                    List<KioskAppDetail> appList) {
        mContext = context;
        mAppList = appList;

        mPackageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Number of times getView method call depends upon gridValues.length
        return mAppList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Number of times getView method call depends upon gridValues.length
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView;

//         if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_app_label);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_app_image);
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        if (!mAppList.get(position).getAppLable().toString()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("Peripheral Settings")) {

            /*int color = Color.parseColor(Util.getStringDefaultPrefValue(
                    mContext, Util.TEXT_COLOR, Util.TEXT_COLOR_DEFAULT));*/

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            String iconSizePer = Util.getStringDefaultPrefValue(mContext, Util.ICON_SIZE_DP, Util.DEF_ICON_SIZE_DP);
            if(iconSizePer != null) {
                if(!iconSizePer.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    int originalIconSize = 60; // This is 100% Icon Size
                    int iconSize = (Integer.parseInt(iconSizePer) * originalIconSize) / 100;
                    int pixel = dpToPx(iconSize);
                    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = pixel;
                    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = pixel;
                    imageView.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            String textSizePer = Util.getStringDefaultPrefValue(mContext, Util.TEXT_SIZE_SP, Util.DEF_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
            if(textSizePer != null) {
                if(!textSizePer.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    int originalTextSize = 18; // This is 100% text Size
                    int textSize = (Integer.parseInt(textSizePer) * originalTextSize) / 100;
                    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
                } else {
                    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
                }
            }

            int color;
            /*= Color.parseColor(Util.getStringDefaultPrefValue(
                    mContext, Util.TEXT_COLOR, Util.TEXT_COLOR_DEFAULT));
*/
            String selectedColor = Util.getStringDefaultPrefValue(mContext, Util.TEXT_COLOR, Util.TEXT_COLOR_DEFAULT);
            if(selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.black));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Black")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.black));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Blue")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.blue));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Cyan")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.cyan));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Dark Grey")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.dark_grey));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Grey")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.grey));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Light Grey")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.light_grey_text));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Green")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.green));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Magenta")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.magenta));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Red")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.red));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("White")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.white));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Yellow")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.yellow));
            } else {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.black));
            }

            textView.setTextColor(color);
            textView.setText(mAppList.get(position).getAppLable());
            // Log.d(tag, mAppList.get(position).getAppLable() + "App lable"
            // + mAppList.size() + "App list size" + position);

            // if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mAppList.get(position).getAppIcon())) {
            // no custom icon, use app's icon
            imageView.setImageDrawable(mAppList.get(position).getDefaultAppIcon());
            // }

            final OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(tag, "app icon clicked ["
                            + mAppList.get(position).getPackageName());

                    Intent i = mPackageManager
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(mAppList.get(position)
                                    .getPackageName());
                    mContext.startActivity(i);

                }
            };
            imageView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        } else {

            Log.d(tag, "In If Home Screen Adapter");

            int color;
            /*= Color.parseColor(Util.getStringDefaultPrefValue(
                    mContext, Util.TEXT_COLOR, Util.TEXT_COLOR_DEFAULT));
*/
            String selectedColor = Util.getStringDefaultPrefValue(mContext, Util.TEXT_COLOR, Util.TEXT_COLOR_DEFAULT);
            if(selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.black));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Black")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.black));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Blue")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.blue));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Cyan")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.cyan));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Dark Grey")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.dark_grey));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Grey")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.grey));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Light Grey")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.light_grey_text));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Green")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.green));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Magenta")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.magenta));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Red")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.red));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("White")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.white));
            } else if (selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Yellow")) {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.yellow));
            } else {
                color = Color.parseColor(mContext.getString(R.string.black));
            }
            textView.setTextColor(color);
            textView.setText(mAppList.get(position).getAppLable());

            // if
            // (TextUtils.isEmpty(mAppList.get(position).getAppIcon()))
            // {
            // no custom icon, use app's icon
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_settings);
            // }

            final OnClickListener onClickListenerr = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(tag, "app icon clicked ["
                            + mAppList.get(position).getPackageName());
                    // Intent i =
                    // mPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(mAppList
                    // .get(position).getPackageName());
                    // mContext.startActivity(i);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        boolean status_for_useage_access_on_app_click = Util
                                .systemSettingsOnUsage(mContext);
                        if (status_for_useage_access_on_app_click == true) {
                            // Intent i = mPackageManager
                            // .getLaunchIntentForPackage(mAppList
                            // .get(position)
                            // .getPackageName());
                            // mContext.startActivity(i);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    mContext,
                                    net.intricare.allowedsettings.PeripheralSettingsActivity.class);
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Util.launchUsageAccessDialog(mContext);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                mContext,
                                net.intricare.allowedsettings.PeripheralSettingsActivity.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            };
            // --------------------------------------------- //
            imageView.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerr);

        }

        // } else {
        // gridView = (View) convertView;
        // }
        /**
         * duplicate code
         */
        // --------------------------------------------- //

        /*if (!mAppList.get(position).getAppLable().toString()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("Peripheral Settings")) {
            int color = Color.parseColor(Util.getStringDefaultPrefValue(
                    mContext, "text_color", "black"));

            textView.setTextColor(color);
            textView.setText(mAppList.get(position).getAppLable());
            // Log.d(tag, mAppList.get(position).getAppLable() + "App lable"
            // + mAppList.size() + "App list size duplicate code"
            // + position);

            // if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mAppList.get(position).getAppIcon())) {
            // no custom icon, use app's icon
            imageView.setImageDrawable(mAppList.get(position)
                    .getDefaultAppIcon());
            // }

            final OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(tag, "app icon clicked ["
                            + mAppList.get(position).getPackageName());
                    try {
                        Intent i = mPackageManager
                                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(mAppList.get(position)
                                        .getPackageName());
                        mContext.startActivity(i);
                    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };
            imageView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        } else {

            TextView textVieww = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_app_label);

            int color = Color.parseColor(Util.getStringDefaultPrefValue(
                    mContext, "text_color", "black"));
            textVieww.setTextColor(color);
            textVieww.setText(mAppList.get(position).getAppLable());

            ImageView imageVieww = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_app_image);

            imageVieww.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_settings);

            final OnClickListener onClickListenerr = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(tag, "app icon clicked ["
                            + mAppList.get(position).getPackageName());

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        boolean status_for_useage_access_on_app_click = Util
                                .systemSettingsOnUsage(mContext);
                        if (status_for_useage_access_on_app_click == true) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    mContext,
                                    net.intricare.allowedsettings.PeripheralSettingsActivity.class);
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Util.launchUsageAccessDialog(mContext);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                mContext,
                                net.intricare.allowedsettings.PeripheralSettingsActivity.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            };
            // --------------------------------------------- //
            imageVieww.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerr);

        }*/

        return gridView;
    }

    public static int pxToDp(int px) {
        return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
        return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i(tag, "touch event");
    }
}
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
TouchyGridView mGridView;
 mGridView = (TouchyGridView) findViewById(R.id.apps_grid);


 LocalBroadcastManager bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(MESSAGE_PROGRESS);
        bManager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);


 mGridView.setAdapter(new HomeScreenAppGridAdapter(HomeActivity.this, mKioskAppsList));
        mGridView.setOnNoItemClickListener(this);
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);



        private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if(intent.getAction().equals(MESSAGE_PROGRESS)){
                //initHomeScreenUI(true);

                /*if(download.getProgress() == 100){
                    mProgressText.setText("File Download Complete");

                } else {
                    mProgressText.setText(String.format("Downloaded (%d/%d) MB",download.getCurrentFileSize(),download.getTotalFileSize()));
                }*/
            }
        }
    };


    // When Download Start, I am sending broadcast using below code

    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.MESSAGE_PROGRESS);
        intent.putExtra("download",download);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(DownloadService.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: While the apk is being downloading try to put gif image as background over the item

Comment: But I want to update progress dialog using progressbar.setProgress(progress);

Comment: I created different class for adapter.

Comment: after receiving broadcast try some thing adapter.notify

Comment: Are you using DownloadManager for downloading ?

Comment: @ADM, I am downloading using retrofit.

Comment: @Pavya Then How can I pass progress value to adapter?

Comment: Is there getView function in your class. If it's has you can updating progressbar.

Comment: Well if retrofit provides you the progress then just set a callback(interface) to notify the item in adapter .

Comment: you cannot set particuler gridview item with progressbar. you should add one item into adapter and set gif image as background

Comment: in broad cast are you sending package name? And add main activity code

Comment: Is there any default progress bar in retrofit? @ADM

Comment: @Nirav Joshi  It is possible .You can have ProgressBar as a part of item_layout of grid view . and make it visible on download started .and set progress with callback .

Comment: @ADM . Exactly, Currently  there is 2 gridview item. ImageView and TextView. Now I added Progressbar and ImageView in RelativeView and set visibility gone in progressbar

Comment: But the problem is how to update progressbar in gridview adapter

Comment: @Pavya, No I am not sending package name in broadcast receiver

Comment: add your model Activity and model class

Comment: Code is added. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps to solve the issue.

First Make sure that Adapter class and activity code is in same class.

1. When You start download send one broadcast receiver for Update UI and manage flag according to that.
2. And Set Visibility true for the Progressbar.
3. Now update a progress bar.
4. Hide Progressbar when download finish.

Comment: Yah That can be possible. I will let you know after check.